# How can you get a detailed error descriptions in Dynamics AX?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, morph-x

When doing many different (obviously) wrong things in A++ syntax I only get "Syntax error" in Description and some number (Err:9999) in Diagnostic ID. This does not help me at all finding out whats wrong so I can fix it. No hint, no nothing!

This is compile time syntax errors that the IDE should just hand to me.

So how can I get more detailed information about what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of showing more information that this "Syntax error" for that error type. Almost always is a missing semicolon or brackets dispaired.

Comment: I´m so hard pressed to believe that! :-( Could you show me some documentation confirming it? Though after searching for few days I´m going to mark this as the answer to morrow if nobody else can dispute your claim.

Comment: There is no documentation about things that can't be done, sorry. I'm working with AX for many years and versions, this is only my personal answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you doubleclick on a syntax error line in the compiler output window, the code editor window opens and displays the code with the syntax error. The part of the code with the error is marked with a red squiggly underline and the cursor is placed at the start of the syntax error. This should make it easy to find out what is wrong.

In addition to what j.a.estevan suggested, in my experience syntax errors also occur because

- you forget the second = symbol in the where part of a select statement
- you unintentionally add a second = symbol when assigning the value of a variable
- you delete a variable in the classDeclaration of a class/form, but it is still used in one of the methods
- a macro is changed/deleted
- an object is changed/deleted and the cross references were not up to date or not checked